# Is there a method called in between touchesBegan and touchesEnded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, touchesbegan, touches

I asked [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/54315/how-to-combine-tap-and-long-hold-gesture-recognizers) on the Stack Exchange Game Development Site about how to combine the tap and long hold gesture recognizers, and received the following answer:

> The way to deal with this is to set a timer once the person taps the phone. The most user friendly scenario that you'd implement would look something like this:
>
> 1. When you detect a tap, set a timer (t = timeToRepeat)
> 2. On each frame, decrease the timer by dt
> 3. If the timer reaches zero, move the sprite a tile and reset the timer
> 4. If the user releases their finger before the first cycle of the timer, move the sprite one tile
>
> Obviously the amount of time that you set your timer to will determine how fast your sprite moves. There are a few variations on this theme depending on the kind of behavior you want as well. For example, you can move the sprite once immediately upon detecting a tap and ignore step #4.

I agree that this is the way to do it, so I am trying to implement this and have come up with the following code to do so:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //This records the time when the user touches the screen
    self.startTime = [NSDate date];
}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    NSTimeInterval temp = [self.startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
    NSTimeInterval holdTime = temp * -1;

    if(holdTime < self.threshold) {
        //Tap
    }
    else {
        //Hold
    }
}
```

This code works but I realized that I should call the timer code while the user is holding down on the screen, not after they finish. So **is there a way to call the code in touchesEnded while the user is pressing down?**

Comment: I dont have answer, But i will try implementing all the delegates and mark breakpoint to check.

Comment: The part that you missed was when they said to "start a timer".  You just recorded the time.  You should start a repeating timer in this method which calls a method at the timer expiration (and moves your sprite).  touchesEnded would then cancel the timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, if the user keeps his/her finger perfectly still there is no method that is called between them.  In practice though, `touchesMoved` gets called a bunch.  You should just use an `NSTimer` though instead of keeping track of the time yourself